# Send email to specific user by using webform

Tags: 7

**Send email to specific user :**

For this i have added a webform **contact to this person** using webform.

after filling the information in webform by anonymous user , a mail should be sent to that user whose profile is  he/she seeing.

**Note**: this functionality should only work for anonymous user and by using webform.

How to achieve this?

Comment: How on the webform does the anonymous user specify the user to be contacted? Is that a custom field on the webform? If not what do you have available to identify the person to be contacted?

Comment: i have placed the link on user profile ,ananomous user can see the profile of  user ,uid is available

Comment: How does the path of that link look like? And how exactly is that "uid" available?

Comment: on clicking link webform opens on user profile of user

Comment: Your last comment is not an answer to my 2 questions in my last comment. Please retry to answer them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the solution by myself

1) Create a hidden field in webform say **username** field.

2)then go to /webform/emails .select the component value that is equal to **username** hidden field you previously created.then edit added component value in **E-mail from address section** select the component radio button instead of Default: abc@yahoo.com radio button.

3)**then create a custom module add this code**

```
 function your_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

 if ($form_id == 'your_webform_id') {
    $uid = arg(1);
   if ( arg(0) == 'user' && is_numeric($uid) ) {
       $account = user_load($uid);
        $form['submitted']['Your-hidden-field-machine-name']['#value']   = $account->mail;
     }
   }

   }
```